# LDAP authentication, pam_mkhomedir and NFS automounted homes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ldap, nfs, autofs

We currently have a setup (running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) with mixed LDAP/NIS authentication and automounted home directories from several servers (with the `auto.home` map distributed over NIS). Everything runs smoothly as long as the user logging in (either with NIS or LDAP) already has a home directory somewhere (i.e., `ls /home/user` successfully triggers its mounting).

I wanted to use pam_mkhomedir.so to have local home directories automatically created for people not having a home on the servers (which works fine on normal setups), but of course this could not work (same problem described in this question: [LDAP/NFS/PAM/AutoFS : mkhomedir PAM plugin failling](https://serverfault.com/questions/58872)), as autofs and pam_mkhomedir could not work together. Any mkdir in `/home` actually fails when automounting is enabled there, therefore making a bind mount inside `/home` is also not a solution.

Does anybody know a good solution to have local home directories created for uses not having a NFS home, knowing that we have no control over the info coming from the LDAP (i.e., users must have their homes in `/home/username`, and autofs is working there), and without hacking into autofs sources? Creating a home on a NFS server at login would be a possibility, but how to do that in a safe way?